# Why does this Ember.js app work locally but not on jsFiddle.net?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, jsfiddle

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/odigity/zS5uu/). Here's the [gist](https://gist.github.com/3843051) with the contents of my local file.

As you can see, the HTML and JavaScript are identical, and I'm loading identical versions of the jQuery, Handlebars.js, and Ember.js libraries. It works as expected locally, but does not render the application template on jsFiddle.net.

I see the following error in the Web Console:

[19:44:18.202] Error: assertion failed: You must pass at least an object and event name to Ember.addListener @ https://github.com/downloads/emberjs/ember.js/ember-latest.js:51

BTW-To test the gist as a local HTML file, make sure to run it behind a web server or your browser won't download the JavaScript libs. If you have thin installed (ruby webserver), go to the directory it's in and run `thin -A file start`, then navigate to localhost:3000/jsfiddle-problem.html in your browser.

Answer (score 3):

If you set the "Code Wrap" configuration on your fiddle to one of the options other than "onLoad" your application will work. Here is an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/ethan/zS5uu/5/).

The reason for this is Ember initializes an application when the jQuery ready event fires (assuming you have not set Ember.Application.autoinit to false). With the jsFiddle "Code Wrap" configuration set to "onLoad" your application is introduced to the document after the jQuery ready event has fired, and consequently after Ember auto-initializes.

See the snippet below from ember-latest, taken on the day of this writing, which documents Ember auto-initialization being performed in a handler function passed to $().ready.

```
if (this.autoinit) {
    var self = this;
    this.$().ready(function() {
        if (self.isDestroyed || self.isInitialized) return;
        self.initialize();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was strange - I couldn't get your fiddle working, specifically your `{{controller.foo}}` call until I disabled autoinit. I am guessing when using jsfiddle the application initialize kicks off before seeing your router. I also noticed with your fiddle the router was not logging any output even when you had enableLogging set to true.

I updated your fiddle to not use autoinit, http://jsfiddle.net/zS5uu/4/. I know a new version of ember-latest was released today, I wonder if anything about initialization changed.